# addStoreFilter() is not working in Magento2.3

Tags: magento2.3

I need to filter the products by store. However, after many try for almost a day, I can't filter products by store.

```
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 

        $productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
        $collection = $productCollectionFactory->create();


        // filter current store products
        $collection->addStoreFilter();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $best_selling_product_id]);
```

`$best_selling_product_id` is an array of product ID's. However, above code returns products from all stores.

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 

    $productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
    $collection = $productCollectionFactory->create();


    // filter current store products
    $storeid = 1; 
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addStoreFilter($storeid);
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $best_selling_product_id]);
```

Comment: Actually, I have given a try for this too

Comment: updated above code, please try

Comment: ok, hold on a moment

Comment: I wish it should work. But Unfortunately no luck.

Comment: hmm how about changing these two lines `$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addStoreFilter($storeid);` to `$collection->addStoreFilter($storeid); $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');`

Comment: I've observed an odd behaviour. When I print `foreach ($collection as $key => $value) {
            echo '<pre>'; print_r($value->getData()); echo '</pre>';
        }`, store_id changes for the same product to selected store.

Comment: the code above works for me. can you try to remove `$collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $best_selling_product_id]);` this line and check if you get the desired result

Comment: Is there any clue why `store_id` in the filtered query changes according to selected store?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92423/discussion-between-magefms-and-butterfly).

Answer (score 1):

Use below code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
        // filter current store products
$collection->setStore($storeManager->getStore());
$collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $best_selling_product_id]);
```

**Note: Do not use objectmanager directly, add dependency to your respective file and use from it**

Comment: Oops... No luck